# Rendering an array of data in a carousel component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm working on a carousel in React JS which currently is rendering a set of numbers:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import {
  Wrapper,
  NumbersWrapper,
  NumbersScroller,
  NumberText
} from "./Numbers.style";

const hundred = new Array(100)
  .fill(0)
  .map((k, v) => ({ key: v, label: v + 1 }));

class Carousel extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      activeNumber: 0
    };
  }

  setActiveNumber(number) {
    this.setState({
      activeNumber: number
    });
  }

  render() {
    const { activeNumber } = this.state;
    const intAciveNumber = Number(activeNumber);

    return (
      <Wrapper>
        <NumbersWrapper
          onClick={() => this.setActiveNumber(intAciveNumber + 1)}
        >
          <NumbersScroller
            style={{
              left: `${130 - intAciveNumber * 55}px`
            }}
          >
            {hundred.map(({ key, label }) => {
              const isNeighbor =
                key + 1 === activeNumber || key - 1 === activeNumber;
              const isActive = key === activeNumber;

              return (
                <NumberText
                  key={key}
                  isNeighbor={isNeighbor}
                  isActive={isActive}
                >
                  {label}
                </NumberText>
              );
            })}
          </NumbersScroller>
        </NumbersWrapper>
      </Wrapper>
    );
  }
}

export default Carousel;
```

Now I'd like to use display custom numbers from an array like this example using the `new` [keyword](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_arrays.asp):

```
const hundred = new Array([100, 150, 200, 250, 400, 500, 650, 780, 830, 900, 1500])
  .fill(0)
  .map((k, v) => ({ key: v, label: v }));
```

However, when I make this change to the array, nothing happens. How can I correctly display the values inside of the component? If there is an NPM library that does this for React (web), I would take that as a solution also. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I have been using this a lot:
https://react-slick.neostack.com/

Works like a charm - and very customizable.

Something along the lines of this would probably work..

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Slider from "react-slick";

export default class SimpleSlider extends Component {
  render() {
    const settings = {
      dots: true,
      infinite: true,
      speed: 500,
      slidesToShow: 1,
      slidesToScroll: 1
    };
    return (
      <div>
        <h2> Single Item</h2>
        <Slider {...settings}>
          {hundred.map(({label}) => (
            <div>
              {label}
            </div>
          ))}
        </Slider>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the values as separate parameters instead of an array like so.

```
const hundred = new Array(100, 150, 200, 250, 400, 500, 650, 780, 830, 900, 1500)
  .fill(0)
  .map((k, v) => ({ key: v, label: v }));
```

Right now, you are creating an array within the **hundred** array at position zero, so when you iterate over the objects with .map, you are only going over a single value, which contains the whole array.
Output of your current implementation of array initialization:
[image]

How it works with the change above:
[image]